# How do I solve this dependency error in openSUSE 13.1 when installing QGIS (master)?

Tags: qgis, installation

I am running OpenSUSE 13.1 and downloading via Yast I get the following error:
nothing provides libpq.so.5()(64bit) needed by qgis-master140102-1.2.x86_64

I get three of these errors, for each of the three qgis downloads (master, grass plugin, master-devel).

I have two options under Conflict Resolution:
1-do not install...
2-break...by ignoring some of its dependencies

What would you folks recommend? Is there something wrong with QGIS in openSUSE?

Comment: libpq is usually from PostGIS or PostgreSQL. What's the output of `zypper wp libpq.so.5`?

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand your question. Should I input that somewhere?

Comment: Sry, you have to enter that into a terminal (command line). I'm not sure if you can check for `what-provides` using YaST Software Manager - but I know `zypper`.

Comment: I put it into the terminal and it said: Loading repository data...reading installed packages...No packages found.

Comment: What if you change just `libpq.so.5` -> `libpq.so`?

Comment: I get the same output

Comment: That's odd. What repo are you getting qgis-master from?

Comment: Not sure but I think the url was from: ttp://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/...  Should I try it again from a different repository?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12362/discussion-between-saultdon-and-oregonian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your main repos is *disabled*; just has to be *enabled*.

I can see that in the output of `zypper lr -u`.

```
#  | Alias                     | Name                               | Enabled | Refresh | URI                                                                      
---+---------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | google-earth              | google-earth                       | Yes     | Yes     | http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/rpm/stable/x86_64                       
 2 | openSUSE-13.1-1.10        | openSUSE-13.1-1.10                 | No      | Yes     | hd:///?device=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_13E8F75D-0:0-part2  
 3 | openSUSE_13.1             | openSUSE_13.1                      | Yes     | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_13.1/
 4 | repo-debug                | openSUSE-13.1-Debug                | No      | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/13.1/repo/oss/           
 5 | repo-debug-update         | openSUSE-13.1-Update-Debug         | No      | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/13.1/                          
 6 | repo-debug-update-non-oss | openSUSE-13.1-Update-Debug-Non-Oss | No      | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/13.1-non-oss/                  
 7 | repo-non-oss              | openSUSE-13.1-Non-Oss              | Yes     | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.1/repo/non-oss/             
 8 | repo-oss                  | openSUSE-13.1-Oss                  | No      | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.1/repo/oss/                 
 9 | repo-source               | openSUSE-13.1-Source               | No      | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/13.1/repo/oss/          
10 | repo-update               | openSUSE-13.1-Update               | Yes     | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/update/13.1/                                
11 | repo-update-non-oss       | openSUSE-13.1-Update-Non-Oss       | Yes     | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/update/13.1-non-oss/
```

In your case, just run `sudo zypper mr -e repo-oss` then you can run `sudo zypper ref` and finally `sudo zypper in qgis-master`.

It's actually probably really easy to "enable a repo" in YaST Software Manager too.